# Matching order of 2 lists and their corresponding terms next to them

Tags: excel, list

I am asking about this in a different more simplified way with 2 lists.

How can I match the order of 2 different lists where columns A and C match on the same rows. Column B is corresponding terms to A and column D is corresponding to C. So I would need those cells to move with their A and C cells.

Example.
Start with this:

[image: [Starting point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh4Dg.png)]

Ending with this:

[image: [End goal matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHtP8.png)]

I tried asking in a different way but it didnt work out

Comment: "Order of 2 lists" seems relative or perhaps not needed. Why not just have a consolidated list with 3 columns. Column A are de-duped titles from both original lists. Then Column B is a vlookup against list A Terms. Then Column C is a vlookup against List B terms. Wrap your vlookups with IFERROR.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is oversimplified. Your result looks like `C` and `D` columns sorted by `C` ascending. But looking to your other question I guess it is not the case.

Would suggest to make a unique "master" list of titles and then use `VLOOKUP` to match *Corr terms* from all your lists.

You can make unique list by copying all titles into one column and then using Excel function remove duplicates. Or with Excel 365 you can use `UNIQUE` formula (`G3` cell in example):

```
=UNIQUE(VSTACK(A3:A10,C3:C10,E3:E11))
```

where ranges are for all title ranges from 3 tables.

Having "master" title list you can now use `VLOOKUP` to match *Carr terms* from all 3 tables (`A3:B10`,`C3:D10` and `E3:F1`1 in example).

Use `=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(G3#,A3:B10,2,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP(G3#,A3:B10,2,FALSE)),"")` in `H3` to match from first table, `=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP(G3#,C3:D11,2,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP(G3#,C3:D11,2,FALSE)),"")` from second in `I3` and finally `=IFNA(if(VLOOKUP(G3#,E3:F11,2,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP(G3#,E3:F11,2,FALSE)),"")` in `J3` from third table.

If you made a "master" list by other than using `UNIQUE` formula, then instead of `G3#` range in `VLOOKUP`'s use range `G3:G12`.

Now you have a complete table, you can use `TEXTJOIN` to make it to one cell for example: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,H3:J3)` in `K3` and dragged down.

[image]

Keep in mind that this will work if titles in those 3 lists are unique per lists as `VLOOKUP` will take only first match.

Also you should really take a look at @JvdV answer to your other question as it gives exact same result except it will work with duplicates inside those 3 separate tables.

Comment: Oh no! yes I pasted that incorrect. I meant to show that the two title lists were out of order from each other. I must have pasted the wrong picture. Checking your submission now!

Comment: Many of the titles match but not all of them and the matching titles have different corresponding terms next to them.

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble using the. Can you fill it in with the specific values as follows?
9291, 8312, 6254

Comment: What do you mean by those values? Are those ranges for 3 lists? A2:A9291, C2:C8312 and E2:E6254?

Comment: Yes those are the ranges =)